# JSONField in Django continues to remain empty even after POST request

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a JSONField in Django. If I issue POST through the browser using Django Rest UI, the data gets entered into the model with no issues. However,when I use Python's requests.post in my application, everything except the JSONField data stores in the model.

Here is my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class Scans(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Server = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Results = JSONField(default=dict)
    Report_Url = models.URLField(max_length=30)`
```

Here is my Serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from .models import Scans   
class ScansSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scans
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my view

```
class ScansData(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        scans = Scans.objects.all()
        serializer = ScansSerializer(scans, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ScansSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request):
        scans = Scans.objects.all()
        scans.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here is my request

```
data = {
    "Name": "dodo",
    "Server": "ubuntu",
    "Report_Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/about/"
}
jsonval = {
    "Results": {
        "Severity_High": 8,
        "Severity_Medium": 7,
        "Severity_Low": 5
    }
}
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/scans/', data=data, json=jsonval)
```

URL

```
urlpatterns = [    
path('scans/', ScansData.as_view()),
]
```

What I see after using requests.post

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "Name": "dodo",
    "Server": "ubuntu",
    "Results": {},
    "Report_Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/about/"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try data in this format .

```
data = {
    "Name": "dodo",
    "Server": "ubuntu",
    "Report_Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/about/",
    "Results": json.dumps({
        "Severity_High": 8,
        "Severity_Medium": 7,
        "Severity_Low": 5
    })
}
```

and remove jsonvalue

```
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/scans/', data=data)
```

Comment: try  requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/scans/', data=json.dumps(data))

Comment: I'm using Django 3.1.4 and a APIView to receive the post request and had to use 

json.loads(resquests.data['Results'])

on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

data = {
    "Name": "dodo",
    "Server": "ubuntu",
    "Report_Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/about/
    "Results": {
        "Severity_High": 8,
        "Severity_Medium": 7,
        "Severity_Low": 5
    }
}
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/scans/', data=data)

Comment: I tried this and got a status 400 response, nothing stores in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Suh and Sachin! I was finally able to sort it out.Turns out json.dumps was indeed the key. Here is what I did to solve the issue.

```
jsonval = {
    "Results": {
        "Severity_High": 8,
        "Severity_Medium": 7,
        "Severity_Low": 5
    }
}

data = {
    "Name": "dodo",
    "Server": "ubuntu",
    "Results": json.dumps(jsonval["Results"]),
    "Report_Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/about/"
}
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/scans/', data=data)
```

Comment: thats great, i have updated my answer, please upvote , if it was useful

Comment: Absolutely! Saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
import json

jsonval = {
    "Results": {
        "Severity_High": 8,
        "Severity_Medium": 7,
        "Severity_Low": 5
    }
}

data = {
    "Name": "dodo",
    "Server": "ubuntu",
    "Report_Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/about/",
    "Results": jsonval["Results"]
}

requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/scans/', data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Got Status 415 Unsupported media type.